# Use grep output as an ln -s directory

Tags: bash, grep, gnu, gnu-parallel, ln

I am writing a bash script where i want to use the grep output below "**06**" in a link i'm creating.

```
echo [super-shows]Super.Show.S06.1080p.BluRay.DD-EX.5.1.x264 | grep -oP '(?<='S')\d{2}(?=\.)'

ln -s /home/Download/[super-shows]Super.Show.S06.1080p.BluRay.DD-EX.5.1.x264 /home/Media/TV/Super.Show/**06**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy with using xargs, propably that is allready installed, if not I'm sure it's available in the package manager for every distribution.

```
echo "[super-shows]Super.Show.S06.1080p.BluRay.DD-EX.5.1.x264" | grep -oP '(?<='S')\d{2}(?=\.)' | xargs -I{} ln -s /home/Download/[super-shows]Super.Show.S06.1080p.BluRay.DD-EX.5.1.x264 /home/Media/TV/Super.Show/**{}**
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great! If i wanted to use grep to echo Super.Show how could i change the regexp to do so?

Comment: @angelsen ```echo "[super-shows]Super.Show.S06.1080p.BluRay.DD-EX.5.1.x264" | grep -oP '(?<=']').*\d{2}(?=\.)'``` for example would output ```Super.Show.S06``` you can easily play around with it to fit your needs

Comment: Figures! I am also able to make directories using grep and xargs, how could i make directory **within** the made directory based of grep output? e.g. /home/Media/TV/Super.Show/06/BluRay

Comment: Eureka! Ended up using parallel. `echo "[super-shows]Super.Show.S06.1080p.BluRay.DD-EX.5.1.x264" | grep -oP (?<='-')\w*(?=\.)' | parallel -N2 mkdir -p /home/Download/{1}/{2}`